# Package updates on debian 8.6

Tags: debian

Checking for new package updates running Debian KDE 8.6 through System Setting, I always get :

```
E:http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources is not (yet) available (503 Service Unavailable)
```

I have tried with konsole to do this through apt-get update but I got the same result.

Do you have any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps: You could comment out the matching line in your apt configuration as a workaround. As long as the service is down you will be not able to update from this source.

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/...
```

Answer (score 0):

> `E:http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources is not (yet) available (503 Service Unavailable`)

The meaning of the output : The url `http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main` doesn't exist , you should edit your `sources.list`:

```
apt edit-sources
```

Edit the following url:

```
http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main
```

as follows :

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Save then update your system.